# What size of pvc pipe should be used to make T for sewer pipe vent?

Tags: plumbing

We have an older home with a cast iron sewer vent pipe. We live in very cold climate. Have heard that a T made with pvc pipe can be used to illuminate the pipe end coming out of the roof from freezing up. Pipe circumference is 4". What size of pvc should be used and how long should the portion that fits down the pipe be?

Comment: Why would you want to light up the end of the pipe? What does that have to do with it freezing or not?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm guessing you didn't mean "used to illuminate the pipe"; what did you mean?

Comment: Did you mean insulate?